# open new page with rel external

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the page automatically, and I would use   `window.location`

how can I add the attribute   `rel="external"`  to       `window.location`

or is there a method jquery?

PAge 1:

```
case 'A1':
console.log("id_groupe_du_page  "+ id_groupe_du_page);
window.location("../etapeA1.html");
```

Page 2:

```
$("#A1").live('pageshow', function()
        {

alert("A1 executer");
        }
);
```

code of Page 2 js not running

Comment: What would this `rel="external"` do? I don't see it making sense in a JS context

Comment: My problem is when I change the second page the javascript code does not executes, this is why I should use rel="external"

Comment: Do you mean navigate to a site external to yours. If so `<a href="http://www.externalsite.com">external site</a>`

Comment: I don't understand. Can you start from the beginning and explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: If you have code that should run on load or .ready then it should be running.  If you navigate to the target page directly does your JS fire?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unrelated to opening the window in a new tab.  There are some errors in your JavaScript that would cause it not to fire.

Change your JavaScript on **Page 2** to:

```
$('document').ready(function () {

     alert("A1 executer");

});
```

Also as of 1.7 `.live` is deprecated and you should avoid being used. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/live/)